# Prevent Android app from running on Windows 11

Tags: android, windows-11

As new Windows 11 has Android app support, it also increases the risk of app tempering. How can we prevent our app from running on a Windows 11 device?

Comment: What kinds of app tampering are you concerned about? I'm not sure I understand how there is any more risk with the app running on Windows.

Comment: "How can we prevent our app from running on a Windows 11 device?" -- primarily, don't distribute the app via Windows 11 channels.

Comment: Android App is not restricted to channel as APKs are openly available on many websites. more risk in the sense its a financial app and people can go a greate extents to exploit it

Answer (score 4):

You're taking the wrong approach.  If you're concerned about your app's security, write your app securely.  Limiting what OSes it runs on won't help.  Especially since you seem to think its more of a concern on Windows than it is on Android, an open source OS anyone can build a customized version of and can have APIs lie to the app.

Comment: If we can limit the environment it can run in it mitigates the risk . you are right but in practical I would prefer prevention better than Cures 

Answer (score 2):

check out `Build.VERSION` class, in there you can find e.g. `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` which is [API lvl](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms) of OS running app (different across devices). I'm very curious what it return on Windows... maybe you will find in there some other useful variable, basing on it you can disable your app UI and functionalities (I very doubt you can prevent installation itself)

Comment: I suspect SDK_INT will not be a unique value, as it'll certainly implement some of the normal SDK levels. But BASE_OS might differ.

Comment: if you check this out please put result in this topic :) besides that: I've upvoted Gabe's answer. Good luck!